# facebook webview and detect the user close event

Tags: facebook, webview

I have an Messenger bot that allows users to go to a Web page on a `WebView`. I want to detect when the user closes the `WebView` by himself. Is there any way to detect this event and go back to my bot? There is an option to add a close button and when the close button triggers can be managed in `MessengerExtensions.requestCloseBrowser.` But can I use it for the default close option in the `WebView` right corner?

Comment: please add a bit of code. to show what you have done so far.